# Recommendation for storing menu hierarchy in DB

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have an food ordering system that has main item such as latte, long black, flat white, espresso, americano etc. Each item is stored in a DB as follows.

*db missing unnecessary columns

```
  +----+----------------+-------------+
  | id | item_name      | price       |
  +----+----------------+-------------+
  | 1  | latte          | 2.0000      |
  +----+----------------+-------------+
  | 2  | long black     | 2.5000      |
  +----+----------------+-------------+
  | 3  | flat white     | 3.0000      |
  +----+----------------+-------------+
  | 4  | americano      | 2.0000      |
  +----+----------------+-------------+
```

I need to add sub-options to each item but each item will have unique set of options for example `americano` will have a milk type, sugar type. Flat white will have a milk type also but will need to be a different menu as americano may not require a milk option so will have a different submenu. For example.

```
   Flat white milk menu 
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | id | item_name      | submenu_id |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 1  | soy            |     1      |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 2  | rice           |     1      |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 3  | regular        |     1      |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 4  | trim           |     1      |
  +----+----------------+------------+

   americano milk menu 
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | id | item_name      | submenu_id |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 5  | soy            |     2      |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 6  | rice           |     2      |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 7  | regular        |     2      |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 8  | trim           |     2      |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 9  | no Milk        |     2      |
  +----+----------------+------------+
```

Then there may be a common item such as sugar...

```
         sugar
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | id | item_name      | submenu_id |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 10 | Sugar          |     3      |
  +----+----------------+------------+
  | 11 | no Sugar       |     3      |
  +----+----------------+------------+
```

What would be the best way to store the hierarchy in the DB? For example flat white would need the values `1,3` americano will need `2,3`. The same kind of system may be required for something that requires many more options. I need to be able to pull these out and load each sub option with javascript.

Comment: Have you tried each your root item has a parent_id of 0 and then each item below has a parent_id of the item you want it to be a sub menu of. like flat white id = 1 and the parent id would = 0 then the items that need to attach to that menu would have the parent_id = 1.

Comment: the subitems will have multiple parent items

Comment: you could create a Map Table i.e you would just have two coloums menuItem, subItem so you could map the same item to many root items.

Comment: The subitem will have subitems that will differ also. For example americano -> americano milk -> sugar. Flat white -> flat white milk -> sugar. Sugar is the same for each

Comment: The map would handle that. example : americano id = 1, americano milk id = 2, flat white id = 3 and sugar id = 4 so the map items would look something like this 1:2 , 2:4 , 3:4 so the map will allow you to give any item a parent id you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does each sub-option belong to one option only or two several options? I imagine that sugar would belong to each option....

In which case, you will need three tables: an options table such as you already have (id/name/price), a sub-options table (id/name) and a join table (option/sub-option). You could probably combine the options and sub-options tables by adding a flag field, although in this case you would have to ensure that the join table is populated correctly.

Comment: It actually gets quite complicated as a user can create sub options and pick and chose which goes with the main item. One main item could have multiple sub options. Not necessarily in the same order! I may have to save the items as an array with each main item.

Comment: Do you want a database structure or a "live", in-memory structure? With a database, a join table as I suggested above would allow the user to choose several sub-options for each option. You would *NOT* want to store the sub-options as an array column in a database table.

Comment: The structure needs to be extracted from the DB and used live. The data will be loaded into a JS array and stepped through to drag up each sub option.

Comment: Does JS have queries which can be iterated? Better to iterate through a query's result set than an array.